# LoaderManager throwing incompatible types error

Tags: android, fragment, android-loadermanager

I am calling `AsyncTaskLoader` in one of the fragments I created. I have imported `import android.app.LoaderManager;` and I am getting error while calling this method `LoaderManager manager = getLoaderManager();`. I have the same thing going in my main activity and there it doesn't throw any error.

It also ask me to import this `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager` instead of `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager`. When I did, it showing the `getLoaderManager()` is deprecated.

My FragmentExchangeList.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FragmentExchangeList extends Fragment implements   
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<ExchangeListData>> {              
    private List<ExchangeListData> mExchangeListData;
    private ListView mExchangeListView;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mSetbaseCurrency;
    private String linkForCurrencyList;
    private static final int CURRENCY_List_LOADER_ID = 2;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exchange_list, container, false);

        mExchangeListData = new ArrayList<ExchangeListData>();
        mExchangeListView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.exchange_list_view);
        mSetbaseCurrency = rootView.findViewById(R.id.set_base_currency);

        linkForCurrencyList = "https://ratesapi.io/api/latest?base="+mSetbaseCurrency.getText().toString();
        LoaderManager manager = getLoaderManager();
        manager.initLoader(CURRENCY_List_LOADER_ID, null, this);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<ArrayList<ExchangeListData>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new ExchangeListBackground(getContext(), linkForCurrencyList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<ExchangeListData>> loader, ArrayList<ExchangeListData> data) {
        mExchangeListData.clear();
        if(data != null && !data.isEmpty()){
            mExchangeListData.addAll(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<ExchangeListData>> loader) {
        mExchangeListData.clear();
    }
}
```

The error is `error: incompatible types: android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager cannot be converted to android.app.LoaderManager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in the past. The `fragment` that you are using is from support library, so you need to use the `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager`  package to the `LoadManager` too.

But searching **about the deprecation**, is because google is deprecating all the stack of loaders, They are recommending to use Jobs. So, to solve your problem use the deprecated package and put a suppress deprecated comment to Android Studio not be annoying.

Comment: I have changed it to `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager` and also I imported `import android.support.v4.content.Loader`. now it showing error as `error: incompatible types: ExchangeListBackground cannot be converted to Loader<ArrayList<ExchangeListData>>`

Comment: You need to create a Loader in another class file extend from Loader, and in the method `onCreateLoader` you need to instantiate your Loader. Follow this: [Android reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders?hl=pt-BR)

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. Now my error is gone when I imported `import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;` instead of `import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;` in the loader. :)

Comment: Great \o/. I am pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 1):

delete `import android.app.LoaderManager;` and add this line `import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager`